# 12 months comparison in R

Tags: r, trend

I want to calculate a trend based on a 12 month rolling comparison, i.e. compare January 2020 with January 2021, for Category `VW` only.

For now my dataset looks like this:

| Dates | Category | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-20 | BMW | 150 |
| 2020-01-20 | VW | 200 |
| 2020-02-20 | BMW | 250 |
| 2020-02-20 | VW | 300 |
| 2020-03-20 | BMW | 220 |
| 2020-03-20 | VW | 250 |
| .......... | ..... |  |
| 2021-01-20 | BMW | 500 |
| 2021-01-20 | VW | 600 |
| 2021-02-20 | BMW | 200 |

What I did for now is importing the table and formatting the date right. I am not sure how to calculate the trend. I saw some functions like `lag` which could be useful but have no concrete plan how to implement it right. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to estimate a trend based on the last 12 months, or do you want to estimate a trend from two months separated by 12 months?

Comment: I want basically for now a trend from the comparison of January 2021 with January 2020. But if you have any solutions for the calc of the trend based on the last 12 months, it could be also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only 1 row per date and category, and assuming all dates have the same day (say 20), then a merge could solve this

```
df=read.table(text="
Dates   Category    Sales
2020-01-20  BMW 150
2020-01-20  VW  200
2020-02-20  BMW 250
2020-02-20  VW  300
2020-03-20  BMW 220
2020-03-20  VW  250
2021-01-20  BMW 500
2021-01-20  VW  600
2021-02-20  BMW 200",h=T)

library(lubridate)

df$Dates=as_datetime(df$Dates)

df2=df
df2$Dates=df$Dates+months(12)

merge(df,df2,by=c("Dates","Category"),all.x=T,suffixes=c("","_lst"))



       Dates Category Sales Sales_lst
1 2020-01-20      BMW   150        NA
2 2020-01-20       VW   200        NA
3 2020-02-20      BMW   250        NA
4 2020-02-20       VW   300        NA
5 2020-03-20      BMW   220        NA
6 2020-03-20       VW   250        NA
7 2021-01-20      BMW   500       150
8 2021-01-20       VW   600       200
9 2021-02-20      BMW   200       250
```

where Sales_lst contains the 12 months earlier value, from which you can calculate your desired trend.

Comment: That looks quite good! The calculation of the trend is then just a division of Sales and Sales_lst, right?

Comment: @UdoGniß Maybe, depends on your definition, in general (y_{t} - y_{t-1}) / (x_{t} - x_{t-1]).

Comment: What if, i might calculate the Trend for Sales based on two metrics? Like taking the previous two months e.g. (JAN 2020 and DEZ 2019) -> build measure;  and the past 10 months (NOV 2019 till FEB 2019)-> build measure; in order  to calculate the delta for FEB 2020 ? How is that possible?

Trend/Delta FEB 2020 = (JAN 2020 + DEZ 2019) / ( NOV 2019 + .....+ FEB 2019)

Comment: @UdoGniß That is a different question, this method is probably not the best, so you are best asking a new question.